# Ошибка времени выполнения

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define n 5
int main()
{
    float A[n][n], B[n][n], C[n][n], R;
    int im, i, j;
    printf("matrix A[%i][%i]:n", n, n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n; i++)
            scanf("%f", &A[i][j]);
    printf("matrix B[%i][%i]:n", n, n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            B[i][j] = sin(i + j);
        }
        printf("5.2f ", B[i][j]);
    }
    printf("n");
    printf("matrix C[%i][%i]:n", n, n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            C[i][j] = A[i][j] + B[i][j];
        }
        printf("%5.2f ", C[i][j]);
    }
    printf("n");
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        im = 0;
    {
        for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
            if (C[im][j] < C[i][j]);
        im = 1;
        {
            R = C[im][j];
            C[im][j] = C[0][j];
        }
        C[0][j] = R;
    }
    printf("matrix C[%i][%i]:n", n, n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            printf("%5.2f ", C[i][j]);
    }
    printf("n");
    getch();
}
```

Comment: И какую же ошибку выдаёт C++? И где? (Ответ "в программе" -- не принимается)

Comment: И исправьте опечатку в строке:

     for (j=0;j<n;i++)

Comment: Особое внимание к замечанию, которое сделал @alexlz. У вас в первом же проходе цикла переменная i вылетает больше n (так как нет условия её ограничивающего) и все. Index out of range.

Comment: Дело даже не в этой конкретной ошибке, а в ее причине. А причина заключается в глобальном объявлении переменных цикла. Если бы переменные были локальными, то компилятор такую ошибку (описку) в коде не пропустил бы.

Comment: @BuilderC, это с какого перепугу компилятор бы не пропустил? Посмотрите на текст -- ошибка объявлениями в заголовке for не ловится.

Comment: @alexlz Да, правда. Я в конкретный текст-то и не смотрел даже. Так написал - из общих принципов ((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка из-за строк вида

```
{ for (j=0;j<n;j++)
  { B[i][j]=sin(i+j);
  }   printf("5.2f ",B[i][j]);
} printf("\n");
```

Уберем для начала дикое форматирование (оно ужасное)

```
{
  for (j=0;j<n;j++)
  { 
    B[i][j]=sin(i+j);
  } 
  printf("5.2f ",B[i][j]);
}  
printf("\n");
```

видно, что строка `printf("5.2f ",B[i][j]);` выполняется за пределами цикла, хотя использует параметр цикла.  По стечению обстоятельств, он будет в данном случае равен 5. И когда дело дойдет до последней итерации по `i`, то будет выход за пределы массива.

Второй участок
    for (j=0;j<n;j++)
      im=0;
      { for (i=1;i<n;i++)
        if (C[im][j]<C[i][j]);
         im=1;
       { R=C[im][j];
         C[im][j]=C[0][j];
       } C[0][j]=R;
      }

Делаем тоже переформатирование

```
for (j=0;j<n;j++)
  im=0;
{
  for (i=1;i<n;i++)
    if (C[im][j]<C[i][j]);
      im=1;
  {
    R=C[im][j];
    C[im][j]=C[0][j];
  } 
  C[0][j]=R;
}
```

Если присмотреться, то здесь вообще фейерверк использования. Все далеко за пределами циклов.

Ну и ошибка, упомянутая [@alexlz](/users/352/alexlz).

Вывод. С++ это не питон. Здесь компилятору глубоко побоку на отступы (ну кроме отдельных специфических случаев).

Код нужно переписать по новому, правильно расставив фигурные скобки и применив адекватное форматирование.

Comment: @KoVadim А "правильно расставив фигурные скобки" -- это как? indent 2.2.11 имеет 4 предопределённых стиля (остальные надо задавать более мелкими параметрами): k&r, gnu, berkley и linux. Какой из них Вы считаете правильным?

Comment: Под словом правильно понималось согласно логической структуре кода. А вот какой стиль предпочитает автор вопроса - это его личное дело. Но пользоваться indent нужно уже тогда, когда получили код-мусорку. А свой код нужно форматировать головой.

Для своих личных целей я предпочитаю K&R стиль.

да, **Срочно** выключите режим зеленого тролля. Срочно.

Comment: Еще  sin(i+j) это ошибка. 

Аргумент д.б. типа double, но это формально. 

А фактически, что (если *осмысленно* ) означает синус от суммы индексов элемента матрицы???

Comment: @avp Почему ошибка? Это C/C++. В языках с более строгой типизацией -- таки да. У тут -- нет. А осмысленно -- тестовые данные без всякого смысла. Задача-то учебная.